# Can Postfix relay/forward to multiple MX servers?

Tags: postfix, mx-record

[diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCoTa.png) I can't post images yet so I've included a diagram link

I have both Fastmail and Zoho configured to receive emails for `user@example.com`. However, for redundancy I want to put Postfix in front of them make it act like the primary MX server. So all incoming email would go to `mx.example.com` and not `mx.fastmail.com` or `mx.zoho.com`.

I've read that Postfix can relay incoming emails to specific addresses, or even SMTP servers, but I haven't found if it's possible for me to define multiple MX servers and make Postfix use BOTH. As you can see, I can't forward emails from `user@example.com` as that'd send emails to itself as that's there the MX records point to.

So as the diagram suggests, the goal is to receive the email at `mx.example.com` and then relay it TWICE to both `mx.fastmail.com` and `mx.zoho.com`.

Is this possible? If not, are there any other tools that can enable me to do so?

Comment: Why do you want to receive every email twice, in two different mail services? If you want redundancy, list both your postfix server and one of fastmail or zoho in your domain's MX records. When one is down the other will receive the mail, and if fastmail/zoho is down, postfix will keep retrying to deliver it for awhile until it comes back up.

Comment: I've seen too many horror stories on hackernews about people losing access to their accounts for whichever reason. If I maintain 2 services that get all my emails, if one is lost the 2nd one will be a copy of the first one (as they both receive all emails). This means that there will be zero downtime and no emails will be lost - and most importantly I'll still be able to send emails out. I hope this clarifies it a bit!

Comment: Consider asking this question on the Postfix mailing list. There you'll often get good input quickly.

Answer (score 0):

> So as the diagram suggests, the goal is to receive the email at mx.example.com and then relay it TWICE to both mx.fastmail.com and mx.zoho.com.

Receiving an e-mail twice is a bit misleading, but **dovecot** has a clean way to symmetrically replicate any received e-mails to another dovecot. To be more precise, it replicates any mailbox action too.

Assuming your aim is **redundancy**, your best option is [dovecot replicator](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Replication). Install and configure it on both mx.fastmail.com and mx.zoho.com

- How it works in brief: Any action on mailbox in *mx.fastmail*.com will be replicated in the same mailbox in *mx.zoho.com* by dovecot service and vice-versa. It applies to incoming e-mails too, which is your aim.
- You can then use the *mx.example.com* as [load balancer](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/director/dovecotdirector/) for incoming e-mails (LMTP) as well as mailbox accesses (POP/IMAP) between the two backends.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wasn't aware of Dovecot replicator. But I'm currently using 3rd party providers and there's no option to install dovecot as they manage everything. I don't know if there's a way around that?